# Unable to list files using tree and tree-strict programs in Linux Manjaro

Tags: tree, manjaro, arch

Using tree in Ubuntu has made working in CLI much more enjoyable. When I switched over to my laptop running Manjaro and tried to install the tree program using snap, it went well and installed without errors. However when I try to run

`~ tree mydir`or just `tree` to list files + dir in the current working directory, I get an error:

```
locales-launch: Data of en_AU locale not found, generating, please wait...
. [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files
```

After some google searching, I came across: The Tree Command (OBSOLETED)
https://snapcraft.io/install/tree-strict/manjaro and decided to give it a shot!

After installing this, I tried to run it:
`~ tree-strict mydir`

Alas! I was met with another error telling me to remove this obsolete package:

```
. [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files

# Snap Obsoletion Notice #
This snap(tree-strict) has now been _superseded_ by the `tree` snap and will no longer recieve any updates.  Please install the `tree` snap and remove the `tree-strict` snap as soon as possible.

If you have any problems regarding the obsoletion, feel free to ask a question on <https://answers.launchpad.net/tree-snap>
```

I've seen posts telling me to just purge locales and reinstall them but can someone point me in the right direction as I am not an expert in Arch Linux. Much appreciated!

Comment: Any reason to use snaps instead of the binary in the filesystem? You can just install using `pacman -S tree`

Comment: @BrunoCriado Snaps just popped up first when I google on how to install tree package. But using pacman has worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

@BrunoCriado suggested using pacman rather than Snaps which has solved this issue.

I was used to having Snaps work out-of-the-box and the thought of using pacman never occured to me.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help you out.